# Why did a link-only answer get 3 upvotes?

Tags: discussion, link-only-answers, specific-answer

This user got 3 upvotes for this very recent link-only answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19422833/2074608

How did this happen?

Note that there is another recent answer with a link to the same site, but I'm not sure if it's self promotion or not.

Comment: Because 3 users thought it was worthy of an upvote?

Comment: It was useful for 3 people = 3 upvotes. Flagging is quite orthogonal to voting. Upvote is described as "is useful", not as "is properly formatted" or "is high quality".

Comment: consider the fact that the user seems to be new to site. He did modify the question after the comment was left and it looks pretty good now. No reason to complain now. Your question has been answered by Bart in the first comment ;)

Comment: @Bart, Molot: or because 3 reviewers in the Low Quality Queue were hungry for badges....

Comment: @S.L.Barth exactly what i was going to say...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In the face of like [24,000 link-only answers with positive score](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/183709/165773) spread over at SO, these most likely look okay for *regular* users.

Don't let the prevailing attitude here at MSO trick you into thinking that wider SO audience shares it. As pointed in the answer linked above,

> [Canonical meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/165773) promoting this attitude has 46K views; that means vast majority of [SO users](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all) have no idea about it, not to mention supporting it (top voted answer has 262 upvotes - a drop in the ocean).
>
> When an inexperienced SO user looks at (one of few tens thousands) link-only answer with positive score, it would be just silly to expect them to think "oh that's bad, it should be downvoted / expanded". I'll venture a guess that they think it's a reasonable way to answer and gain reputation. Every link-only answer with positive score "flags" (pun intended) its readers that it's OK to answer that way and serves further proliferation of this style of answering...

Comment: Yep. The majority of users won't know about most of of the rules/regulations/principles, and I would not be surprised if a significant amount of them don't even care. Goal number one is getting an answer to a question. Such is reality.

Comment: @Bart Agree. I would phrase this as _the majority of users are presented with strong evidence that goes against rules/regulations/principles..._