# Not sure why this answer was downvoted, but I want to avoid mistakes in the future

Tags: discussion

I recently posted an answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24831437/cookie-timeout-length/24831555#24831555) thread here, and got downvoted. Was there something wrong with my answer? I genuinely thought the link I provided would more than answer his question (since the questions are very similar). I just want to avoid making the same mistake twice. Was I too short? Did I come off like a jerk? any insight is appreciated

Comment: It's a link-only answer. Link-only answers are not considered good answers and are subject to downvotes/deletion.

Comment: There are no "threads" on Stack Overflow. Stack Overflow ***is not a forum***, it's a Question and Answer site.

Comment: Related: [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/162704)

Comment: @Cupcake ahh sorry, poor choice of words I suppose.

Comment: @Yannis hehe that post cleared some stuff up for me. lessons learned

Comment: @Cupcake: I actually do call the container that consists of the question and answers as thread as I have not come across a better term to refer to it as a whole just yet. What you probably meant though is that comments are not acceptable as answers on Stack Overflow to be clear.

Comment: @psoshmo: these links are better suited for the duplicate handling system, or comments if offsite link.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You'll undoubtedly see this comment posted to your answer in a matter of minutes from someone else anyway, but here it is a tad early: (It was in fact posted about a minute before this post; I guess I typed too slow.)

> While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the
>   essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.
>   Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

On top of that, if you feel that a question is a duplicate of another Stack Overflow question you should *vote or flag that question as a duplicate* so that it can be closed as such. You should not just post an answer to the duplicate question.

Comment: fair enough on both points. lesson learned, won't happen again. Thanks for the fast response

Comment: also, should I just delete my answer then?

Comment: @psoshmo Sure.  It'll be deleted by others if you don't.  You can save them the time and effort of doing so.  If you really feel that the questions are duplicates though, please take the time to flag the questions as duplicates.

Comment: I cant flag as a duplicate yet :( sorry for the compound screw up. there goes my precious rep

Comment: @psoshmo You need 15 rep to flag posts.  You have 21.  That is enough to flag the post.  You don't have enough rep to *vote* to close the question as a duplicate, but you can flag it, which will bring it to the attention of people who *can* vote to close it.

Comment: 4.Flag to close (questions only)* 1.Duplicate question*
2.Off-topic (with sub-reasons)*
3.Unclear what you're asking*
4.Too broad*
5.Primarily opinion-based*

5.Very low quality (i.e. no amount of editing can salvage the post) (only posts scoring 0 or less)
6.Other (needs ♦ moderator attention)

 * these options will not appear in the flag menu until you have earned 50 reputation (the amount required for commenting).
am I just misunderstanding this? thought I needed 50 to flag questions.

Comment: @psoshmo Right, guess you do need another 29 rep then.

Comment: @psoshmo: knowing rep can be damaged(or improved) for *any* reason *any*, well almost any, other user feels appropriate makes it not so precious, *or* meaningful. Just today I was down voted twice on two, albeit uninspiring, accepted answers with no explanation. Life goes on; good to see you care enough to try to improve yourself though.

Comment: Sometimes adding a comment to the effect of "Possible duplicate of <link to question here>" is good enough to attract attract close votes.

Comment: Then, why has this question been answered and not been closed as duplicate of one of the link-only-answer questions? E.g.  [1](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251514/how-should-accepted-link-only-answers-be-handled?rq=1), [2](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256089/how-to-handle-link-only-low-quality-posts) or [3](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251006/flagging-link-only-answers?rq=1)

Comment: @ThomasW. Because the question isn't asking how to handle link only answers, it's asking what the problem is with his post.  On top of that, none of those covers cases where the link is another SO question.